# Input with type="date" does not support a placeholder attribute

Tags: html, semantic-ui, placeholder

Is there any way to display placeholder for input with type='date'. I'm using Semantic UI for react and here is my code.

```
        <Form>
           <Form.Group widths='equal'>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>Warranty Period</label>
                <Input
                  id="startDate"
                  name="startDate"
                  type='date'
                  placeholder={'Start Date'}
                  value={state.startDate}
                  onChange={onHandleChange}
                  className='add-link-input'
                />
              </Form.Field>

              <Form.Field>
              <label style={{ color: 'transparent' }}>.</label>
                <Input
                  id="endDate"
                  name="endDate"
                  placeholder='End Date'
                  type='date'
                  value={state.endDate}
                  onChange={onHandleChange}
                  className='add-link-input'
                />
              </Form.Field>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
```

Comment: That isn’t what `placeholder` is for. These two fields should be inside a `fieldset`. “Warranty Period” should be a `legend`. Start Date and End Date should be your `labels`. The `label`s should be associated with the `input`s using the `for` attribute.

Comment: @Quentin can you please add an example code